# How to pass arguments to a model class?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm a total newbie in Django and  I'm trying to pass the properties to a TodoItem instance in my views.py file:

```
def addTodo (request):
    new_item = TodoItem(content=cont)
    new_item.save()
```

In the example above I get to pass only one argument, but what if I have to pass several? This is my model:

```
class TodoItem(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    types = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    time = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can do this way

```py
TodoItem(content=content_data, types=types_data, time=time_data)
```

or, if you have a dict

```py
data = {
    "content": "content_data", 
    "types": "types_data", 
    "time": "time_data"
}

TodoItem(**data)
```